# Flutter: What widgets would I use to create this screen?

Tags: flutter

I am so puzzled with Flutter.  I created an application 7 years ago for Windows Phone that had this screen:

[image: Windows Phone screen]
Can anyone tell me what layout widgets (and maybe even what order?) I would use to create this screen with Flutter?

I plan to use Flutter Studio to design and generate the code.  Hoping that will help me get a grasp.

Comment: Have you gone through the [widget index](https://flutter.io/docs/reference/widgets)?

Comment: Hi, Matt.  Thanks for responding.  I have.  I think I need a ListView, but could be that I need a GridView or ListBody.  But the bigger problem in deciding how to embed the widgets.  I am not sure how to build the widgets in some sort of hierarchy to get what I want.

Comment: Okay. Generally you should have _some_ code that shows an attempt at solving the problem but I know how hard it can be to search for something when you're not sure where exactly to start so I took a crack at it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what my implementation looks like:

[image]

And the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyHomePage(),
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.white,
        brightness: Brightness.light,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 5,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              'Cool Storage',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'Databases',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.storage,
                          size: 56,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                  flex: 16,
                  child: ListView.separated(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Container(
                        height: 80,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Text(
                                    'Records',
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    '#',
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Text(
                                    'Category Name',
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.blue[800]),
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    'Date Modified: 01/01/1970',
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              Icon(
                                Icons.arrow_right,
                                color: Colors.blue[800],
                                size: 56,
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border(
                            bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[300]),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    itemCount: 20,
                  )),
              Expanded(
                flex: 3,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        'Grants for You',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 24,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'USAFundingApplications.org',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 20,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
          child: Stack(children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.cloud),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.more_horiz),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Obviously you will need to dynamically populate the ListView, play with the padding, import Font Awesome for the OneDrive icon, use the [auto_size_text](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/auto_size_text) package to make sure text scales well on most devices (this screenshot is from a Nexus 5; the font looks much too small on a Pixel XL), maybe replace the current header with a proper AppBar, etc. but this should be enough to get you started

Comment: OMG.  Thank you, Matt!  Not only does this give me the exact code I needed, it's going to be a great learning sample to get started on, as I'm already familiar with the Windows Phone version.  If you were local, I'd buy you a beer.